# Storing camera image in a specific folder by creating in android

Tags: java, android, image, storage

```
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            open();
         }
      });
   }
   public void open(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

      imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
   String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);// this is the location /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO 
});
```

when the button imgFavorite is clicked it opens the default camera after taking picture it stores in the default location called `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO`.
 But I have to store the capture image in a specific folder by creating in the android code. I have tried many examples but its not working .
can anyone tell me the snippet for my code to create a folder and store the capture image.

Answer (score 0):

```
//camera stuff  
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

//folder stuff   
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();

File imageFile = new File(imagesFolder, "SC_" + timeStamp + ".png");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score -1):

While opening camera you can specify the path to store image clicked by your camera. Have a look at

```
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            String imagePath = "filename" + ".jpg";
                            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Directory_Name" + File.separator+ "" + Constants.ORN);
                            root.mkdirs();
                            if (!root.exists()) {
                                root.mkdir();
                            }

                            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Directory_Name" + File.separator + "" + Constants.ORN, imagePath);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                            mImageCaptureUri = outputFileUri;
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

                    }
                });
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: `if (!root.exists()) {
                                root.mkdir();` You should also check the return value of mkdir() and not continue if it fails. Display a Toast instead.

Comment: Yeah that should be added. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: how the code should be inside `@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      
});`

Comment: `Constants.ORN` ORN cannot be resolved error is arising

Comment: @Vanitha No need to have anything within onActivityResult() since we are defining the location for the image initially itself before opening the camera.

Comment: @Vanitha Constants.ORN is just name for the your image. In my case I was storing a image with the ORN no for each image to maintain it's uniqueness.

Comment: what can i do to solve Conatans.ORN error ? Also I have to display the captured in the imageview that is i have done in `onActivityResult`

Comment: It is just image directory in which your images would be stored. For eg: File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Directory_Name" + File.separator+ "MyImages");

Comment: To show in imageview you need to read the image from the same directory File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Directory_Name" + File.separator+ "" + Constants.ORN);

Comment: after taking picture `java.lang.runtime exception` is coming Null pointer exception,  but it created a folder and stores the image

Comment: @Vanitha  Please share you code on this email id: bhatnagar.mayank0@gmail.com. Will check it and revert back on the same

Answer (score -1):

try this code.

```
imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        open();
     }
      });
   }
public void open(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile()));//
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
   }

private File getOutputMediaFile() {
    // make a new file directory inside the "sdcard" folder
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myApp");

    // if this "Camera folder does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        // if you cannot make this folder return
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // take the current timeStamp
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    File mediaFile;
    // and make a media file:
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    currentFilePath = mediaFile.getAbsolutePath();
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: Again this awfull `getOutputMediaFile() `. CreateFileName() it should be called.